# Child View invisible after addView() on API 16

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, layoutparams

I have a problem with `Views`, but only on API 16 :-(

There is a `CustomView`, which looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="top_container"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LineartLayout
        android:id="labels"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now what happens in code is that on `onLayout()` of the view, if `changed==true`, I query an adapter object for a set of `LabelViews` and one `ContentView`. I put the labels into the `labels` `LinearLayout` and the content into `content` `FrameLayout`.

It works great, except on API 16, where the labels and content are queried from the adapter, added to the respective containers, but are not shown! :-( Moreover, the containers actually resize correctly, so the `Views` have measured dimens, just no visual data displayed :-(

By trying several solutions I have noticed that if I add the content `View` with `LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, XX)` where XX is an actual number, it will show the views...

Any ideas? Was there some change in the `ViewGroup` logic after API 16 that could have caused that?

**EDIT:**

This is how the invisible child view shows in tha output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top` (in the above structure it is the direct child of `top_container`):

```
android.widget.LinearLayout{42960190 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f036f app:id/labels}
  com.example.view.pricebox.CheckoutLabelView{42614a18 V.E...C. ... 0,0-0,0}
    android.widget.RelativeLayout{43118438 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
      android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{4310feb8 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f0371 app:id/label_name}
      android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{421b8080 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f0372 app:id/label_icon}
    com.example.view.pricebox.CheckoutLabelView{4261f8a8 V.E...C. ... 0,0-0,0}
      android.widget.RelativeLayout{4207e4e0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
        android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{43129410 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f0371 app:id/label_name}
        android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{4205d938 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f0372 app:id/label_icon}
      android.widget.FrameLayout{42960870 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f0370 app:id/content}
        com.example.view.pricebox.checkouts.CheckoutView{41db1fd0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
           android.widget.FrameLayout{42d73308 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f0367 app:id/content_button_container}
              android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{4224d3e0 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f0368 app:id/content_button}
              android.widget.ProgressBar{41ab5288 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f0369 app:id/content_button_loading}
           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{4273cd08 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f036a app:id/content_label1}
           android.widget.RelativeLayout{43100b20 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f036b app:id/content_stuff_container}
              android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{42554f58 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f036c app:id/content_icon1}
              android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{423beee0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f036d app:id/content_icon2}
              android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{41e02ed8 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0f036e app:id/content_label2}
```

Comment: execute `adb shell dumpsys activity top` and post its output

Comment: Well I have checked the Android Tools vie dump, it shows the containers to have no children. But in code, if I breakpoint right after the addView(), the container reports having one child

Comment: so you are saying that you called `ViewGroup#addView` and `ViewGroup#getChildCount` is not increased?

Comment: It is, that is the point. The View is just not showing. I run your command, it shows the invisible view, I will post that part in a sec

Comment: so post the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top` before and after calling `addView` (you can just limit it to view tree)

Comment: Updated with the output

Comment: all of your views have [0,0-0,0] dims [left,top-right,bottom], even those that are not children of `app:id/content`, what are laout params of `app:id/labels`?

Comment: I see, but the containers - 'labels' and 'content' - actually take space on the screen :/

Comment: how come if they are 0,0-0,0? i run the same command on some test activity and the results are here: http://pastebin.com/2f2UeSQ4, notice the numbers after `......`, they are not 0,0-0,0

Comment: And what Android version are you running it against?

Comment: Android 4.4 API level 19

Comment: Could you try API 16? It is working fine > 16 for me as well :-(

Comment: let me see, ... hmm sorry i have no API 16 image to run